# Execute code when Rails is finished streaming a download

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, download, streaming

I have a streaming download in my Rails 4 application, it downloads a csv file using an Enumerator and I was wondering if there is a way to execute code once the streaming has completed, aka the Enumerator is done?

The reason I need to execute code once the streaming download is finished is because in creating the CSV I had created some temporary tables in the database that I need to delete once the download is done.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

1) Create and launch a task with Sidekiq

2) Declare a callback: after_update or after_create after the data is recorded.

3) Set up a cron job using a Ruby script.

4) Handle the download process as a Microservice using RabbitMQ.